# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) LDAvis

Tags: pickle, lda, pyldavis

I am new to Python and Data Science in general. I am trying to work on some LDA visualizations, but for some reason I keep getting the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Type Error: an integer is required (got type str)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMXw9.png)

```py
import os
LDAvis_data_filepath = os.path.join('./ldavis_prepared_'+str(number_topics))
# # this is a bit time consuming - make the if statement True
# # if you want to execute visualization prep yourself
if 1 == 1:
    LDAvis_prepared = sklearn_lda.prepare(lda, count_data, count_vectorizer)
with open(LDAvis_data_filepath, 'wb', 'utf-8') as f:
        pickle.dump(LDAvis_prepared, f)
        #load the pre-prepared pyLDAvis data from disk
with open(LDAvis_data_filepath,'rb', 'utf-8') as f:
    pickle.dump(LDAvis_prepared, f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-4459335c1578> in <module>
----> 1 with open(LDAvis_data_filepath, 'wb', 'utf-8') as f:
      2         pickle.dump(LDAvis_prepared, f)
      3         # load the pre-prepared pyLDAvis data from disk
      4 with open(LDAvis_data_filepath,'rb', 'utf-8') as f:
      5     pickle.dump(LDAvis_prepared, f)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is the 4th parameter to `open`, not the 3rd.  Two minutes looking at the documentation would have told you that.  And your second `pickle` call should almost certainly be `load`, not `dump`.

```
with open(LDAvis_data_filepath, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pickle.dump(LDAvis_prepared, f)
    #load the pre-prepared pyLDAvis data from disk
with open(LDAvis_data_filepath, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pickle.load(LDAvis_prepared, f)
```